# Passing Array Value as Parameter causes undefined

Tags: javascript, parameters, undefined

My Array:

```
     var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
```

Set Function to Button:

```js
var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

for (var idx = 0; idx < alphabet.length; idx++) {
  var bttn = document.createElement("button");
  bttn.innerText = alphabet[idx];
  bttn.onclick = function() {
    this.disabled = true;
    checkIfWordContainLetter(alphabet[idx]);
  }
  document.getElementById("hangmanContent").appendChild(bttn);
}

function checkIfWordContainLetter(letter) {
  alert(wordToGuess);
  alert(letter);
}
```

Causes `undefined` when I pass `alphabet[idx]` as parameter but if I pass for example `'a'` it alerts `a`.

Comment: This Q&A should be closed. Please run my edit on your snippet and the error message should be enough to solve the issue yourself :)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: I don't believe that's the issue they're talking about. Clearly that element needs to exist, and hasn't been included in the example code, but the `undefined` will be displayed because of the *"function in a loop"* problem.

Comment: @squint Ah right, and this has been answered a lot of times.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```js
var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
for(var idx=0;idx<alphabet.length;idx++)
  {
   var bttn = document.createElement("button");
   bttn.innerText = alphabet[idx];
   
   bttn.onclick = function () {this.disabled=true;
   
   checkIfWordContainLetter(this.innerText);
   }
   document.getElementById("hangmanContent").appendChild(bttn);
  }



function checkIfWordContainLetter(letter)
 {  
  alert(letter);
  alert(letter); 
  
 }
```

```html
<body>
<div id="hangmanContent"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a issue related to scopes.

When you click the button, `idx` is equal to 26, because the `for` already ended, this index doesn't exists on array.

You can simple correct this changing `var idx` to `let idx`, but note that this is implemented only on modern browsers.

A legacy solution could be:

```
for (var idx = 0; idx < alphabet.length; idx++) {
    var bttn = document.createElement("button");
    bttn.innerText = alphabet[idx];
    bttn.onclick = (function (index) {
        return function () {
            this.disabled = true;
            checkIfWordContainLetter(alphabet[index]);
        }
    } (idx));
    document.getElementById("hangmanContent").appendChild(bttn);
}
```

Read: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution:

```
var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
for(var idx=0;idx<alphabet.length;idx++)
{
        var bttn = document.createElement("button");
        bttn.innerText = alphabet[idx];
        bttn.onclick = function (idx)
        { 
           this.disabled=true;
           checkIfWordContainLetter(alphabet[idx]);
        }.bind(this, idx);
        document.getElementById("hangmanContent").appendChild(bttn);
}

function checkIfWordContainLetter(button)
{       
    //alert(wordToGuess);
    alert(button.innerText); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should understand javaScript closure.
When you clicked one of those buttons, the event handler will be excuted. You exposed the idx in the `checkIfWordContainLetter(alphabet[idx])` to be 1,2,3,4,.....However, it will always be (alphabet.length + 1). They all refer to the same place in memory.